# Module not found: Can't resolve '*.module.css'

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React. How can I fix this.? when *className* added the error shown. My Employees.js file is,

```
import classes from '*.module.css';
import { Paper, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import EmployeeForm from './EmployeeForm';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme =>({
    pageContent:{
        margin:theme.spacing(5),
        padding:theme.spacing(3)
    }    
}))

export default function Employees(){
    return(
        <>
            <Paper className={classes.pageContent}>
            <EmployeeForm /> 
            </Paper>
               
        </>    
    )
}
```

The error is,

```
Module not found: Can't resolve '*.module.css' in 'C:\Users\react_ui\src\Pages\Employees'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you are importing module.css incorrectly
replace your line no.1 with this `import "./module.css"`
and make sure your module.css is in the same directory.