# Module not found: Can't resolve './Page.module.css' Next 13

Tags: javascript, heroku, webpack, next.js, vercel

I get this error when running `npm run build` on `Vercel` and `Heroku` but not on my local computer:

`Module not found: Can't resolve './Page.module.css'`

I try to import this file from `app/page.tsx` and they are both in the same directory, the cases match too. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

The line causing the issue from `page.tsx`:

```
'use client'
import styles from "./Page.module.css"
```

`next.config.js` only contains environment variables. `package.json` and webpack settings have NOT been touched in any way.

Comment: What about `import "./Page.module.css"`? Also, see: [Module not found: Can't resolve '*.module.css'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67402280/22152755)

Comment: @LightningMcQueen This is a module file, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice. Also, see: [How do I resolve a 'module not found' error?](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error) and [Next 13 CSS modules support doesn't load stylesheets from client components](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/42039)

Comment: @LightningMcQueen This worked! I used the `git config core.ignorecase false` because apparently git was ignoring the case for this specific file, which is very strange. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, always ready to help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [How do I resolve a 'module not found' error?](https://vercel.com/guides/how-do-i-resolve-a-module-not-found-error)

> One possible cause for this issue is the fact that some filesystems are case-insensitive, however Vercel deployments use a case-sensitive filesystem. Because of this, it is possible that when you change the letter-casing in filenames on your local machine, Git will only pick up changes in your respective static [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) statements. This would mean that your repository is now syntactically incorrect, resulting in a build error when deploying the repository on the Vercel platform.

If you're using git, the solution is to run the following command in your environment:

```
git config core.ignorecase false
```